# Have any Christian denominations or high-profile churches publicly presented a theological case against 'vaccine passes' for churches?

Tags: denomination-survey, covid-19

Where I live, injection passes ('vaccine passes' or 'health passes') are widely used to discriminate against uninjected people in basic civic life and travel, including most recently the government making it mandatory for certain churches (and in all cases, churches can opt for it and receive the carrot of greater occupancy capacity in return, currently).

Have any Christian denominations or high-profile churches publicly presented a theological case against injection passes ('vaccine passes' or 'health passes') for churches?

Answer (score 1):

The CDF of the Catholic Church has presented a document which would seem to imply that it would be immoral to bar people without vaccine passes from public life. [This note on Covid 19 vaccines](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20201221_nota-vaccini-anticovid_en.html) makes reference to previous Church documents regarding vaccine usage and the guidance of conscience, but the important part of the letter is as follows:

> the licit use of... vaccines [made from aborted stem cells] does not and should not in any way imply that there is a moral endorsement of the use of cell lines proceeding from aborted fetuses. Both pharmaceutical companies and governmental health agencies are therefore encouraged to produce, approve, distribute and offer ethically acceptable vaccines that do not create problems of conscience for either health care providers or the people to be vaccinated.
>
> At the same time, practical reason makes evident that vaccination is not, as a rule, a moral obligation and that, therefore, it must be voluntary. In any case, from the ethical point of view, the morality of vaccination depends not only on the duty to protect one's own health, but also on the duty to pursue the common good. In the absence of other means to stop or even prevent the epidemic, the common good may recommend vaccination, especially to protect the weakest and most exposed. Those who, however, for reasons of conscience, refuse vaccines produced with cell lines from aborted fetuses, must do their utmost to avoid, by other prophylactic means and appropriate behavior, becoming vehicles for the transmission of the infectious agent. In particular, they must avoid any risk to the health of those who cannot be vaccinated for medical or other reasons, and who are the most vulnerable.

Since vaccination may create an objection of conscience in faithful Catholics, it is reasonable to conclude that it would be unjust to require vaccination in order to participate in public life. Possibly, if a vaccine were available the use of which did not constitute remote cooperation with evil, one could make a case from this document that governments have a right to require it in pursuit of the common good.

Comment: Thanks for this - at least it's something. If this is the strongest position on this the CC has, though, that's incredibly weak tea.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is that the Church appears (in my interpretation) to have no issue with vaccine mandates so long as there are no legitimate objections from conscience or prudence. So the answer can't be a strong "yes" or "no" because that nuance needs to be applied.